# WooCommerce product images not being cropped

Tags: caching, woocommerce

In WooCommerce > Settings > Product > Display, I've set the product image size as:
[image]

However, on a [single product page](http://www.tempertemper.com.au/test/product/white-with-hazelnut/), the product image is 600 x 600px, which is what it used to be, before I made the change above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the product image dimensions are changed, you need to  regenerate the thumbnails. The following plugin is recommended : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Check the [documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/adding-product-images-and-galleries/#section-4)